# Enable blocks automatically when a theme/module is installed

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I developed a Drupal theme and a few modules. The theme defines special `regions` where the blocks from my modules can be displayed.

In the present condition, first I have to install/activate the modules, then install/enable the theme and then manually enable/configure the blocks. i.e., I have to specify where each block should be displayed.

Is there a way I can set this task to do automatically. That is when I install both the themes and modules, the blocks should be automatically enabled and set in their correct regions.

Comment: Try slide 28 at http://www.slideshare.net/guest6fb0ef/blocks-in-drupal - I'm not sure if this works in D6

Answer (score 1):

The context module will let you keep the position of blocks in code. http://drupal.org/project/context

Features http://drupal.org/project/features will let you save panels to code, but that is more complicated than context if you are not already using panels.

Both are not very easy to learn, but there are not many other options :)